# Need Help Understanding Why $\Delta \vec{v}$ is Perpendicular to $\vec{v}$

Tags: acceleration, vectors

I am confused about the statement of how vector $\Delta \vec{v}$ is perpendicular to vector. I highlighted the statement in pink. I ended up copying the image of the right vector $\vec{v}$ in the velocity isosceles triangle and moved its tail to touch the tail of vector $\vec{v}(t)$. It does not look perpendicular so could someone clarify my misunderstanding?
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is only true if ${\bf v}$ just changes direction but keeps the same length. If ${\bf v}$ and ${\bf v}+ \Delta {\bf v}$ have the same length, then
$$
{\bf v}\cdot {\bf v}= ({\bf v}+ \Delta {\bf v})\cdot  ({\bf v}+ \Delta {\bf v})= {\bf v}\cdot {\bf v}+ 2{\bf v}\cdot \Delta{\bf v}+ (\Delta {\bf v})\cdot (\Delta {\bf v})
$$
so as $\Delta {\bf v}$ gets small we must have ${\bf v}\cdot \Delta{\bf v}=0$. i.e. they become perpendicular.

Comment: **$v⋅\Delta v=0$** is not sufficient for perpendicularity, as **$\Delta v$** tends to zero.

Comment: Beautiful explanation. Thank you Mike and Yukelid <3

Comment: @yukelid It is suficient, since $\mathbf v\cdot\mathrm d \mathbf v$ is a first order differential term and cannot yield an exact value $0$ until the term itself vanishes.

Comment: @ FakeMod alright... that makes sense